# Web API one SQL connection to all users

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

I have a SQL server database with 200 concurrent users limitation. I want to keep the first connection created by any user opened and use it with all other users through my C# Web API. Is that possible?

Comment: Let the connection pooling do it's job, it knows what it is doing.

Comment: I would strongly advise against the idea. Especially if you expect to have around 200 concurrent users, then all queries will be queued up one after another, and executed one at a time - very slow. (When/if you do reach 200+ concurrent users, then you should be able to afford hardware/hosting package upgrade)

Comment: upgrade the hardware is the best solution to avoid being slow

Answer (score 3):

`SqlConnection` is not intended to be used concurrently, so to do what you want would mean synchronizing all access, *especially* if there are transactions involved, or anything involving temporary tables that live longer than a single command. It can be done, but it isn't a good idea.

Note that `SqlConnection` is disposable, and when disposed: the *underlying* connection (that you never see) usually goes back to a pool. If you use *consecutively* (not concurrently) 200 `SqlConnection` instances, you *might* have only used a single underlying connection.

If you *must* put a hard limit on your concurrent connections, you'll have to create your own pool (which might be a pool of one), with your own synchronization code while you lease and release connections. But: it won't be trivial.

Comment: Couldn't one just specify [`Max Pool Size=n`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) to limit the total (and concurrent) number of pooled connections?

Comment: @DanGuzman that will most likely just lead to exceptions like "error getting connection from the pool" (I forget the exact phrasing); you'd need to be very careful with a simple approach like that